# How to visualize mass spectrometer data with plotly?

Tags: python, visualization

Mass spectrometers output analyzation data usually in form of a [mass chromatogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry#Data_representations). I need a visualization of the output data. The x-axis represents the retention time, the y-axis represents the signal intensity and the z-axis represents the mass frequency. I need the signal intensity vs. retention time (y vs. x) and the signal intensity vs. mass frequency (y vs. z). [Consider this short introductional video about how the visualization should look like](https://youtu.be/CK7LccWgmls).

The data may be represented as [profile or centroid data](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264435105/figure/fig4/AS:195944877432835@1423728307694/A-profile-a-and-centroid-b-version-of-the-same-spectrum-The-profile-raw-data.png). But w.r.t. data representation this does not make any difference because the measurement samples are still discrete w.r.t. z-axis (mass frequency).

I'd like to use [plotly Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) to visualize the output data in a dashboard. However I could not find a suitable [3D chart example](https://plot.ly/python/3d-charts/). How do I get the visualization I am aiming for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Needle Plot example [here (dash-bio.plotly.host)](https://dash-bio.plotly.host/dash-needle-plot/) or [here (dash-gallery.plotly.host)](https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-needle-plot/) which is suitable to visualize the data in 2D as well as a [3D Stem Plot example](https://plot.ly/~philgoddard/19/_3d-stem-plot/#/) to visualize the data in 3D.